# jQuery timeout function to run if a user is inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a jQuery timeout script that runs after 30 minutes, however, it is constantly running and I only want it to run if the user has been inactive for that amount of time.  How do I go about doing this?

```
$(function(){
    var timeout = 30000;

    $(document).on("mousemove", function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    })
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.post("../php/logout.php", {}, function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                location.replace("../pages/timed_out.php");
            }
        }, "json");
    }, timeout);
})
```

Comment: Setting `timeout` to zero won't stop anything. The `timeout` will still execute. If you want it to not execute, you need `clearTimeout(timerid)`

Comment: `timeout = 0` means run the supplied function every `0` seconds. You're going to shutdown your server very fast with a loop like that...

Comment: You used clearTimeout incorrectly. Take a look at both answers, they are saying the same thing. You actually are destroying and recreating the 'setTimeout' object when you use clearTimeout. This may cause lag on your browser.

Comment: Just as an FYI, please add any changes as an edit to the bottom of your question in an additional code snippet. If you correct your original content your entire question will become invalid for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reset timeout by clearing it using timeout's ID (which can be obtained as `setTimeout` function result) in `clearTimeout` and setting timeout again:

```
$(function()
{
    var timeout = 30000;
    var timer = 0;

    setTimer();

    $(document).on("mousemove", function()
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        setTimer();
    });

    function setTimer()
    {
        timer = setTimeout(function()
        {
            $.post("../php/logout.php", {}, function(response)
            {
                if (response.success == "1")
                {
                    location.replace("../pages/timed_out.php");
                }
            }, "json");
        }, timeout);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Robert you're welcome. Yes, `clearTimeout` use timeout's ID, which can be obtained as `setTimeout` function result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset the 'timeout', then just changing the timeout variable won't do anything. You would need to actually clear the timeout using clearTimeout()

To do this, here is what you'd need to do...

```
function restartTimeout() {
    timeoutHolder = setTimeout(function(){
        $.post("../php/logout.php", {}, function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                location.replace("../pages/timed_out.php");
            }
        }, "json");
    }, 30000);
}

$(function(){
    $(document).on("mousemove", function(){
        clearTimeout(timeoutHolder);
        restartTimeout();
    })
    restartTimeout();
})
```

Take note of the fact that I assigned a variable to 'hold' the `setTimeout()` as that is necessary to be able to clear it.